# Laravel one to many relationship, store array of values

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, laravel-5.4, relationships

Having two talbes.
One is `product` other one is `tags`.
defined 1 to many relationship.
For prodcut user will type many tags. how do i store those tags id in product table under `tag_id` column. this tag id is in foreign key relation with tags table

Comment: you should use many to many relationship for that

Comment: @Kristian, but the product is unique (only one product), but it has many tags. so i think its `one to many` relationship. why do u want me to go many to many?

Comment: because one product have many tags, and one tag can be tagged to many products, right?

Comment: @yes, u r right. so it will come under many to many..! i will look into that